# Version 12.1.1 unable to type ">"

Tags: bugs, front-end

**Bug introduced in 12.1.1**

---

Since I upgraded to version 12.1.1 I am unable to use > (Shift+.). When I type Shift+. the cell that I am typing in converts to Python. What am I doing wrong?

---

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- Create a text cell and enter some misspelt words. Make sure that they are underlined in red. Enable spell-checking if necessary.
- Create an input cell, enter some characters, then enter `>` *not as the first character*
- The input cell will (incorrectly) convert to an external language cell.

Comment: Interesting. It seems that this is only true if the cursor is at the beginning of the input cell.

Comment: Do not type `>` as the very first character of a new input cell. This is a shortcut for creating an external language cell, just as `*` is a shortcut for creating a new item cell. Valid Mathematica code never starts with `>`, so there should be no need to start a cell with this character. If you still want to have this as the first character, type something else first, then type `>`, then delete the other characters you typed.

Comment: @Szabolcs is there a listing of all these Cell shortcuts?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't know, I never came across one, but I never looked for them either. *I think* (not sure) one can set this shortcut in the stylesheet, so it may differ from notebook to notebook.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be in `Default.nb`, e.g. for `Item` style there is `StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab" -> "Subitem", "*" -> "Subitem"}`.  I'm surprised if there is not a documentation page on this, but I cannot recall seeing one either.

Comment: This is such a bad design choice that I'd say this is a bug.

Comment: @user21 Why is that?

Comment: Because it tried to do something I never want to do - call python. When I edit inequalities like x>2 and move in front of the x and type another > it will open python. Now I have to remember edit inequalities in a specific way and I have to remember that even though python is irrelevant for me.

Comment: @user21 Does this command work in 12.1.1 and what does it return? `CurrentValue[{"StyleDefinitions", "Input", StyleKeyMapping}]`

Comment: @user21 I think it's a good feature (I use `*` all the time), but I also think it should only trigger when `>` or `*` is not only the first, but the *only* character. It should not trigger when editing an existing cell. It should only trigger when creating a new cell by starting to type with a horizontal (i.e. not in-cell but in-between-cells) input cursor.

Comment: @Szabolcs, that would certainly be better. With * the issue is not a dominant because you can always use " " (space) for multiplication. But even with that I never use * (alpha) I think there should be a option to switch these off altogether.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `CurrentValue[{"StyleDefinitions", "Input", StyleKeyMapping}]
{"=" -> "WolframAlphaShort", "*" -> "Item", 
 ">" -> "ExternalLanguageDefault"}`

Comment: @Szabolcs Were you aware that you can type `**` to create a *Subitem* and `***` to create a *Subsubitem*?  I did not realize this until now, from reading the stylesheets.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I did not know. I usually do *, Tab.

Comment: Wolfram has put a New version of V12.1.1 on their website. As far as I can see they fixed the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open menu **Format** > **Edit Stylesheet...** and paste this *below* the "Inheriting base definitions from" cell:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"], StyleKeyMapping -> {}]
```

Choose **Yes** when prompted to "interpret the text" then close the ***Private Style Definitions*** Notebook.

This should remove these automatic Cell conversions from Input cells for the working Notebook.

You can save the *Private Style Definitions* Notebook and define it as the new default stylesheet to make this change persist.

---

If you wish to preserve this functionality but make its entry less accident-prone consider this instead, used as above:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"], 
  StyleKeyMapping -> {
   KeyEvent["=", Modifiers -> {Control}] -> "WolframAlphaShort", 
   KeyEvent["*", Modifiers -> {Control}] -> "Item", 
   KeyEvent[">", Modifiers -> {Control}] -> "ExternalLanguageDefault"
  }
]
```

Now you will need to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you type the character <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>*</kbd>, or <kbd>></kbd> to enter each of these Cell types.

Comment: Oh great, thank you! In particular the  `*` thing annoyed me quite a lot, I really cannot stand it when an editor changes my code without my consent...

Comment: I confirm that this works for getting around this bug in 12.1.1 (since you don't have 12.1.1).

Comment: @Szabolcs Would you please check if my Modified method prevents the bug from triggering by simply typing `>` at the point you indicate?

Comment: Yes, it prevents the bug, but the new shortcuts (with Ctrl) do not work.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hm... you use Windows, right?  They do work in 10.1 under Windows 7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I was testing on macOS. It could be a Mac-specific shortcut conflict.

Comment: @Szabolcs Maybe try `Command` as the modifier rather than `Control`?

Comment: The first solutions worked for me. I use Windows 10.

Comment: @wdacda Glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 12):

That is a known bug in 12.1.1. WRI is going to publish a new build.

Issue and workaround see here:

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2006722

Disabling spell checking helps in the mean time:

Preferences  > Interface > Check spelling as you type

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Changing preferences does not fix the behaviour for Input cells.

Comment: This is the workaround recommended from a Wolfram Developer (see the link to the Wolfram community forum in the answer) and I tried it on my system (MacOS 10.15.5) where it works. The input cells are not converted to external language cells anymore after disabling spell checking.

Comment: At least for me on Windows 10 and on Linux that does not work. Maybe you use macOS?

Comment: Before reinstalling 12.1.1 I checked `SystemInformation["Kernel", "ReleaseID"]`. The old one with the bug is `"12.1.1.0 (6938439, 2020060901)"` the new one without this bug is `"12.1.1.0 (6959458, 2020061902)"`